# Disable breadcrumb on View in Drupal Commerce Kickstart

Tags: 7, views, commerce, breadcrumbs

I am using Drupal Commerce Kickstart. I have been able to disable the hard coded menus by [this advice](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/discussions/8026/commerce-kickstart-disable-main-menu-and-breadcrumb) - specifically my own post at the bottom. Unfortunately this has not disabled the breadcrumbs on certain Views I have created. The Views in question show a single product. One of the views shows content: Full content and the other just draws in node fields from the products. I have a view that doesn't call in any products and this does not show the breadcrumb trail.

The breadcrumb must be hardcoded somewhere as it doesn't appear in the blocks area. It seems to be set to show the breadcrumb in the preface first area.

I would appreciate some advice on where to disable this breadcrumb. Failing that are there any tools in drupal that you can use to trace back to find where things (like the breadcrumb) are getting generated from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to disable the breadcrumbs entirely? If so, with kickstart, you can do so at:

Appearance > Settings > Commerce Kickstart Theme > Toggle advanced elements

It looks like commerce kickstart 2 uses the crumbs module (https://drupal.org/project/crumbs) to handle breadcrumbs (that's what I see in a local install from late July).

I haven't worked with Crumbs, but the documentation is here: https://drupal.org/node/1004394

Comment: Brilliant! That was easy - thanks. I didn't know that setting was there and thought I was going to have to modify the theme templates! This is especially good as it disables the kickstart breadcrumb but does not affect the Easy Breadcrumb that I have chosen to replace it with.